# Trying to edit archive.php to only show post extract, with featured image

Tags: posts, loop, excerpt

I am using two themes (full and desktop), so I am trying to get them to behave in the similarly.

The archive.php for the mobile theme is doing what I want, which is to just show the title and post excerpt.  I think this is the bit of code that does that:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The archive.php for the desktop site is showing whole posts, where I want it to only show the excerpt, as well as featured images.

```
<div <?php post_class() ?>>
   <span class="postmetadata"><?php the_category(' / '); ?> &mdash; <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'mythemename' ), '', ' &mdash; '); ?>  <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'No Comments', 'mythemename' ), '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></span><br/>
      <small><span class="datef"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span><br /><?php the_time('M \'y'); ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php _e( 'Permanent link to ', 'mythemename' ); ?><?php  the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

   <div class="entry">
      <?php the_content( '<em>Continue reading &rarr;</em>' ); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>             
</div>
```

I don't know it does not use a php function to do all that.  How could I replace that with something that will show all the same stuff, but only the post excerpt, with featured image?

Answer (score 2):

To replace the full content with the excerpt, change

```
<?php the_content( '<em>Continue reading &rarr;</em>' ); ?>
```

To

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

To display the featured image use this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
```

Note: Make sure you have this next snippet somewhere in your theme's functions.php file

```
//add theme support for post thumbnails
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you edit your answer to include how to add the 'Continue reading' links for excerpts?  Also, posts without excerpts are truncated with [...] at the end, but there is no link.